# My python blackjack game is not working as intended

Tags: python, while-loop, blackjack

The problems are:

1. Upon typing n to stand and winning, it doesnt ask the user again if they want to play a game of blackjack.
2. And upon winning it also does not ask the user if it wants to play, straight up just starts the game once again.

Please help me solve this, I lost all hope while debugging...
p.s. #clear and #art are placeholders

```
import random

active_game = True  # - Active flag

def restart_game():
    # clear()
    # print(logo)

    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    cards_player = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
    cards_dealer = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]


    def total(cards_entity):  # count someone's cards
        return sum(cards_entity)


    print(f"  Your cards: {cards_player}, current score: {total(cards_player)}")
    print(f"  Dealer's first card: {cards_dealer[0]}")

    def final_score():
        print(f"    Your final hand: {cards_player}, final score: {total(cards_player)}")
        print(f"    Dealer's final hand: {cards_dealer}, final score: {total(cards_dealer)}")

    def winner(): #-checks result of move
        if total(cards_player) == 21:       # player got 21
            if total(cards_dealer) == 21:
                print("You both scored a blackjack. It's a draw! ‍♂️")
                final_score()
                restart_game()
            else:
                print("You scored a blackjack. You won! ")
                final_score()
                restart_game()

        if total(cards_player) > 21:           # player went over 21
            if 11 in cards_player:
                i = cards_player.index(11)
                cards_player[i] = 1
            else:
                print("You went over. You lost! ")
                final_score()
                restart_game()

        if total(cards_player) < 21:        # player got less than 21
            if total(cards_dealer) > 21:
                print("The opponent went over. You won! ")
                final_score()
                restart_game()
            if total(cards_dealer) == 21:
                print("The opponent got 21! You lost! ")
                final_score()
                restart_game()

    def move():
        if input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ") == "y":
            cards_player.append(random.choice(cards))
            cards_dealer.append(random.choice(cards))
            print(f"Your cards: {cards_player}, current score: {total(cards_player)}")
            print(f"Dealer's first card: {cards_dealer[0]}")
            winner()
        else:
            cards_dealer.append(random.choice(cards))
            winner()
    move()

while input("Would you like to play a game of Black Jack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    restart_game()
print("I'm out!")
```

Comment: dont call restart game inside the function just let the function exit and you will return back to your while loop to ask if they want to play again, if they choose yes then you will trigger the function again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `restart_game()` statement from each branch of `winner` function with `return`.

In this way, after each game you would return to the while loop, where you called the `restart_game()` function.

Final Code:

```py
import random

def restart_game():
    # clear()
    # print(logo)

    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    cards_player = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
    cards_dealer = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]


    def total(cards_entity):  # count someone's cards
        return sum(cards_entity)


    print(f"  Your cards: {cards_player}, current score: {total(cards_player)}")
    print(f"  Dealer's first card: {cards_dealer[0]}")

    def final_score():
        print(f"    Your final hand: {cards_player}, final score: {total(cards_player)}")
        print(f"    Dealer's final hand: {cards_dealer}, final score: {total(cards_dealer)}")

    def winner(): #-checks result of move
        if total(cards_player) == 21:       # player got 21
            if total(cards_dealer) == 21:
                print("You both scored a blackjack. It's a draw! ‍♂️")
                final_score()
                # restart_game()
                return
            else:
                print("You scored a blackjack. You won! ")
                final_score()
                # restart_game()
                return

        if total(cards_player) > 21:           # player went over 21
            if 11 in cards_player:
                i = cards_player.index(11)
                cards_player[i] = 1
            else:
                print("You went over. You lost! ")
                final_score()
                # restart_game()
                return

        if total(cards_player) < 21:        # player got less than 21
            if total(cards_dealer) > 21:
                print("The opponent went over. You won! ")
                final_score()
                # restart_game()
                return
            if total(cards_dealer) == 21:
                print("The opponent got 21! You lost! ")
                final_score()
                # restart_game()
                return

    def move():
        if input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ") == "y":
            cards_player.append(random.choice(cards))
            cards_dealer.append(random.choice(cards))
            print(f"Your cards: {cards_player}, current score: {total(cards_player)}")
            print(f"Dealer's first card: {cards_dealer[0]}")
            winner()
        else:
            cards_dealer.append(random.choice(cards))
            winner()
    move()

while input("Would you like to play a game of Black Jack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    restart_game()
print("I'm out!")
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, it solved the first problem, however if the input is "n" (anything else than "y") then the loop is broken and the program just asks "Would you like to play a game of Black Jack?" why would that be the case if at this point typing "y" works just fine?

Answer (score 0):

> Upon typing n to stand and winning, it doesnt ask the user again if they want to play a game of blackjack.

This line makes sure that the user will not be asked to play a game of blackjack if the user input is not `y`.  Since `n` is not `y`, it will not ask the user again upon typing `n`:

```
while input("Would you like to play a game of Black Jack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    restart_game()
```

> And upon winning it also does not ask the user if it wants to play, straight up just starts the game once again.

Instead of `return`ing from the `restart_game()` function, this calls it again, so the code doesn't return to the while loop:

```
            if total(cards_dealer) > 21:
                print("The opponent went over. You won! ")
                final_score()
                restart_game()
```

Comment: I switched every restart_game() to a return statement, yet still upon typing "n" it just skips to "Would you like to play a game of blackjack" and i'm confused because nothing breaks the loop upon typing "y"

Comment: you must be running some other code.  copy-paste the code you have above and run it, and press 'n'.  It will exit

Comment: sorry, my question was a bit badly written, I meant that it throws typing "n" while in a game, as in to stand throws me out of the whole game, why would that be?